# Sort a list with a string like an int

Tags: c#, list, linq, sorting

I have a list of objects`List<Batch> batchesList new List<Batch>();`with fields  `string orderNo` and `int lineNo`

I print "orderNo-lineNo"

I want to sort it by orderNo then lineNo. The problem I have is that using linq's sort(), this will sort as a string, thus 11AG131-13 would actually come before 11AG131-2

```
batchesList.Sort((x, y) => (x.orderNo + x.lineNo).CompareTo(y.orderNo + y.lineNo));
```

Thanks for help

Comment: If you want them to be sorted as int's you have to convert them to `int` before sorting.

Comment: I'm in a car writing in a mobile... Try OrderBy(int.tryparse(your string))The by(int.TryParse(secondstring))

Comment: Just so I am clear.. you want `11AG131-2` to come before `11AG131-13` even though `11AG131-13` could have a `lineNo` that is less than `11AG131-2`'s `lineNo`?

Comment: @T_Roy `2` is the `lineNo` and `11AG131` is the `orderNo`.

Comment: @juharr ohhhhh I see now.. I was interpreting that all to just be the `orderNo`.. okay I see now.  Sorry about my confusion

Comment: There is the separate issue of ordering the `orderNo`  But that's only an issue if it's length can vary like "2AG131" and "11AG131"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var sortedBatches = batchesList.OrderBy(b => b.orderNo)
                               .ThenBy(b => b.lineNo)
                               .ToList();
```

Comment: This is also a good approach

Comment: @J.D. It's identical to yours. ;)

Comment: If I am reading the OP question clearly, they want `11AG131-2` to come before `11AG131-13`? If so, your solution produces the outcome that the OP has already experienced

Comment: Yes and this code will do it because 2 is before 13 :)

Comment: @T_Roy No, this will put the 2 before the 13 because `lineNo` is an `int`.  The OP's issue is that they sort on a string concatenation of the values.

Answer (score 1):

```
var newList = (from x in batchesList orderby x.orderNo, x.lineNo select x).ToList();
```

Comment: This is missing the `select`.

Comment: LOL, right you are. I'll fix it now.

Answer (score 0):

There's an idiomatic approach to ordering on multiple values:

```
batchesList.Sort((x, y) => {
    var i = x.orderNo.CompareTo(y.orderNo);

    if (i != 0) { return i; }

    return x.lineNo.CompareTo(y.lineNo);
});
```